# converting the sql function to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert the following funciton creation to work in MySql

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DistinctList
(
    @List VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim CHAR
)
RETURNS
VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ParsedList TABLE
    (
        Item VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    DECLARE @list1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT, @rList VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@list)) + @Delim
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)

    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @list1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @pos - 1)))

        IF @list1 <> ''
            INSERT INTO @ParsedList VALUES (CAST(@list1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)))

        SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos+1, LEN(@list))
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
    END

        SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+',','') + item
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM @ParsedList) t

        RETURN @rlist
END
```

I found this function at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/15/sql-server-remove-duplicate-entry-from-comma-delimited-string-udf/

Comment: Don't store things in comma-delimited lists.  Use junction tables instead.  That way, you can just use regular SQL to do what you want, instead of downloading arcane functions from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why people have down graded my question.
Anyway I was able to come up with the answer.

```
 Delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION DistinctList
(
List TEXT,
Delim CHAR
)
RETURNS
TEXT

BEGIN
 DECLARE list1 TEXT;
 DECLARE Pos INT;
 DECLARE rList TEXT;
 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ParsedList;
 Create temporary table if not exists ParsedList
 (
Item VARCHAR(60)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;


SET list = CONCAT(list, Delim);
SET pos = length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(list, delim, 1));
WHILE (pos > 0) DO
 SET list1 = SUBSTRING(list, 1, pos);
 IF list1 <> '' THEN
  INSERT INTO ParsedList VALUES (list1);
 END IF;
 SET list = SUBSTRING(list, pos+2);
 SET pos = length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(list, delim, 1));
END WHILE;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Item) FROM ParsedList INTO rlist;
RETURN rlist;
END//
Delimiter ;
```